# References required vs Ism-dodges

Tags: discussion

In this (old) question on [Was Math invented or discovered](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1/37256)

The accepted and highest rated [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/4/37256) says:

> "Intuitionists" believe that mathematics is just a creation of the human mind. In that sense you can argue that mathematics is invented by humans. Any mathematical object exists only in our mind and doesn't as such have an existence.
>
> "Platonists", on the other hand, argue that any mathematical object exists and we can only "see" them through our mind. Hence in some sense Platonists would vote that mathematics was discovered.

A [comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1/was-mathematics-invented-or-discovered/4#comment515_4) with 58 upvotes says:

> I don't think this is a good answer. It reminds me too much of academic philosophers' evasive ism-dodges, i.e. when you ask them 'Does you argument fail because of X?' and they respond: 'Well if you're a Y-ist then no and if you're a Z-ist then maybe yes, but I'm not sure which one I am yet etc etc.' - The schools themselves mean nothing and people who haven't explored the issue independently should not, I believe, get told to look up a certain school of philosophy as their point of first contact

What is the position of the community on this?

---

My own position, subject to modification, FWIW:

I dont like ism-dodges much. They are ok in comments

Answer (score 4):

A good answer to a question like this should draw attention to the fact that there are different approaches to the philosophy of mathematics and as a result there are different answers to the question. The fact that platonists and intuitionists disagree is relevant, so it is worth mentioning. For me, the reason why it is not a good answer is that it is too short and provides no explanation. It amounts to little more than: Go and look up the definition of platonism and intuitionism within mathematics.

Instead it would be helpful to clarify exactly what the distinction is about, talk about why there are different positions, summarise the main arguments for and against, and perhaps mention who the main protagonists are. That said, it seems a little harsh to me for the answer to be deleted.